# How can a minor constituent of an alloy, like carbon in steel have such a profound effect?

Tags: materials, metallurgy

In steel that is 0.65% carbon by weight, barely one in 34 atoms is carbon (assuming no other additives/impurities). How can such an **outnumbered** constituent make such a big difference? Surely many of the iron atoms are not touching any carbon.

Comment: Hint: crystal *boundaries*; edge vs. bulk properties

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steel Discusses it. A few precipitates have a large effect.

Comment: Think about the big strength difference 0.1 % C makes in "micro  alloyed "steels.